Does hitting the armour still do any damage?
Occasionally enemies will block damage and I see a shield.

Is all my damage being mitigated? Am I wasting ammunition if I continue to fire?

Not completely.
That shield icon indicates that your target is blocking; they take some damage, but it is heavily reduced. Charged melee attacks can crush their guard, or you can parry their attack to create a window.
Alternately, the guard only covers the front arc; work with your squad to outflank the enemy and pour on fire to the unguarded sides.

Would a charged Plasma shot break the guard also?

I haven't tested that myself, but it's possible; I know melta weapons can guard crush
